# What is the magnetic field at the walls of a cavity with conducting walls and containing EM radiation?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

If electromagnetic radiation is confined in a cavity with perfectly conducting walls, the total electric field at the walls (i.e., both its components tangential and normal to the walls) must vanish. If the electric field were nonzero at the walls, it would exert forces on the free electrons causing them to move, and they'll quickly redistribute themselves to cancel off any electric field. Using Faraday's law, $${\rm curl}~ \vec{E}=-\partial_t\vec{B},$$ we find that $\vec{B}={\rm constant}$. How can we argue that $\vec{B}=0$? This is the boundary condition that one uses, for example, in waveguides.

Answer (score 0):

Your premise is wrong. A cavity whose walls are made of an ideal conductor, zero resistivity, the *tangential* component is zero but not the *normal* component of the electric field. An electric field normal to a perfect conductor cannot move any charges sideways, it points in the "wrong" direction and by definition there cannot be charge motion in the normal direction.

In contrast, for the magnetic field the normal component is zero but not the tangential component.

Note that the roles reverse at the so-called magnetic walls that waveguide engineers like to introduce sometime to simplify analysis. Magnetic walls are defined by having the normal component of the electric field and the tangential components of the magnetic field be zero.

Electric walls and magnetic walls are complete analogues of short circuits and open circuits, resp., in circuit analysis using Kirchhoff's equations. A short circuit can sustain arbitrary current without a voltage drop and an open circuit an arbitrary voltage without a current. This is exactly what these walls do: an electric wall can sustain any surface current but no voltage along the current (tangential E field is zero), while a magnetic wall can support any voltage along the wall (nonzero tangential electric field) but no current.

Comment: I am not sure. The expression for the skin depth, $\delta=\sqrt{2/\mu\sigma\omega}=0$,  for a perfect conductor $\sigma\to\infty$. Also, see the line from Griffiths (Sec. 9.5.1, Third edition), "We'll assume the waveguide is a perfect conductor so that $\vec{E}=0$ and $\vec{B}=0$ inside the material itself."

Comment: I am sure exactly because of the relationship you quoted for skin depth, as conductivity $\sigma \to \infty$, resistivity $\rho = \frac{1}{\sigma} \to 0$, then $\delta \to 0$, all currents are surface currents and all charges are surface charges. For further details see Collin: "FOUNDATIONS FOR MICROWAVE ENGINEERING" pp39-44 or any standard book in EM theory.

Comment: Stated more "physically", if the field were zero *on* the wall of a closed cavity then there would not be a field inside either. This is a consequence of the Ignatowski equations, [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations)